# ReadTimeout threw an exception when converting byte array to Stream

Tags: c#, asp.net

I got this error

```
ReadTimeout = '((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'.
```

My code is.

```
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);     //Problem generates here//
```

Thanks..

Comment: The exception is not thrown at the line you indicate. ((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception...

Comment: Does the exception occur only when debugging? It would throw an exception if you watch the object because `MemoryStream` does not support timeouts, but it should not affect your program (based on the two lines of code you posted).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [ReadTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout.aspx)/[WriteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.writetimeout.aspx) properties **only if the stream support timing out**.
You can check this via the [CanTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.cantimeout.aspx) property. If the CanTimeout property returns false all access to these properties **should** raise an InvalidOperationException.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code and I needed the MemoryStream to be used as email attachment:

```
string filename=@"C:\images\myimage.img"
MemoryStream result = new MemoryStream();
MemoryStream source = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(filename));
source.WriteTo(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

The `ReadTimeout` property must be overridden, in the base `System.IO.Stream` class it always throw `System.InvalidOperationException` error [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.readtimeout.aspx).

<strike>The solution is not to cast `ms` to the base type when reading the timeout:</strike>

```
int readTimeout = ms.ReadTimeout;
```

Edit: didn't check before posting.. MemoryStream also does not override that property - meaning timeout for such stream is not implemented.

You have to either use other implementation of Stream class that does override the `ReadTimeout` property, or write your own implementation.

Comment: If the exception does indeed occur at the `MemoryStream(byte[], int, int)` constructor as Mia suggests, wouldn't this be a framework bug and certainly not by design? Also I thought the `virtual` method would end up in the actual class even if you cast it to its base?

Comment: When I run I get 'Parameter is not valid.' I QuickWatched my stream ms and from that i came to a conclusion that ----ReadTimeout = '((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' and WriteTimeOut= '((System.IO.Stream)(ms)).ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Comment: @C.Evenhuis no this error can't come from the constructor `MemoryStream` I just double checked its code.

Comment: @Mia see my edit.. you just don't have that property available. What you need it for?

Comment: @Mia You can safely ignore exceptions that only appear when QuickWatching an object.

Answer (score -5):

You should be careful about the type of image in database, if your image is too big then you must use LONGBLOB and not BLOB.

Comment: LONGBLOB is a MySQL thing. This question has nothing to do with databases.