# Memory stream exception C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am trying to let user download image that is stored in database as base64 string, which works fine but when I inspect `stream` while debugging I get

> `stream.ReadTimeout` threw an exception of type `System.InvalidOpertationException`

and

> `stream.WriteTimeout` threw an exception of type `System.InvalidOpertationException`

So I'd like to know if this could cause major problems for me.

```
[HttpGet]
        public IHttpActionResult DownloadImage(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var bill = _billFactory.Get(id);
                var attachment = bill.Attachment;
                byte[] img = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(attachment);

                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(img);
                HttpResponseMessage httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StreamContent(stream)
                };

                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
                {
                    FileName = "image.jpg"
                };

                httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                ResponseMessageResult responseMessageResult = ResponseMessage(httpResponseMessage);
                return responseMessageResult;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is standard behaviour of Stream in combination with the debugger. The debugger wants to read the data of the stream but the concept of a stream is that it reads only on command (your code).

Comment: @Aldert so you want me to Invoke something or wha?

Comment: No, what I am saying that when you hoover over the variable, it is logic that it gives you the error. You are already stating: Everything works WELL. The error you get when hoovering over is totally WELL :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReadTimeout threw an exception when converting byte array to Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487860/readtimeout-threw-an-exception-when-converting-byte-array-to-stream)

Answer (score 3):

`MemoryStream` does not support timeouts. That's why you get the `System.InvalidOperationException`

This won't be an issue.